# Converting ASCII TEXT to Binary

Tags: perl, hex, ascii

I have to convert an ASCII file to Binary. The ASCII file contains a twelve digit hex number in ASCII format. For an input string of 123456789ABC,  I need a six byte output of 0x12\0x34\0x56\0x78\0x9a\0xbc.  Here is the solution that worked. Thanks for the help.

```
my $filename = 'Hub_Device_ID.txt';
my $outfile= 'Hub_Device_ID.bin';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
         or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
open(my $of, '>:raw', $outfile)
         or die "Could not open file '$outfile' $!";
  binmode($of);

  while (my $row = <$fh>){

    chomp $row;
    print "Chomped row\n";
    print $row, "\n";


    my $bytes = pack 'H*', $row;
    print $bytes, "\n";
    print $of $bytes;


    close $of;
    close $fh;

    print "Done\n";
```

}

Comment: Paul, the code you have posted is unreadable and will not compile. You are asking for free help from a world full of strangers. Please be respectful to us: indent properly what you have and correct the syntax errors.

Comment: *"The ASCII file contains only 12 characters with ASCII characters from 0 thru F"* That is a list of 23 characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`. What do you really mean? How should they be "converted to binary"? Someone has told you to use `unpack 'C*'`. Do you know what it does?

Comment: I have not used this site before and had issues getting it to format correctly.  It does compile and run.  I have made some progress in that it properly stores values x01 for 1, x02 for 2, etc. but cannot get x0A for A, x0B for B, etc. I don't seem to be able to edit my original post to fix indentation.

Comment: @PaulGigliotti I've done it for you -- only the indentation, of course; it's your code as it was posted. (Please look through the help pages in the future. They are very good, short and clear.)  Now can you see what is there and fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I need the script to convert an ASCII 0 thru 9 (0x30 thru 0x39) to 0x00 thru 0x09 and store in the output file as such.  I have that part now working.  The issue is converting ASCII A thru F (0x41/0x61 thru 0x46/66) to 0x0A thru 0X0F and storing it as such in the output file.

Comment: When I run the script the print out looks great, but the contents of the out file for A thru F are incorrect.
    123456789abc 
    49505152535455565797989932
    between 0x30 and 0x39
    1
    between 0x30 and 0x39
    2
    between 0x30 and 0x39
    3
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   4
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   5
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   6
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   7
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   8
   between 0x30 and 0x39
   9
   between 0x61 and 0x66
   A
   between 0x61 and 0x66
   B
   between 0x61 and 0x66
   C
Done

Comment: With an input ascii file of 123456789ABC, (303132 etc) my output is now 010203040506070809101112.  The desired output is of course 123456789ABC

Comment: Your last comment says that the desired output for `123456789ABC` is `123456789ABC`. Are you really claiming you just want to copy the file?

Comment: @zdim: Your amended code doesn't compile either!

Comment: @Borodin  I tried to be clear, sorry if that failed: _I didn't change their code_, I only corrected indentation.  (For one, they left out a closing brace.)  If I start fixing that then I'd have to also make sure that all else is well ... etc. I just made it more readable, and warned them in a comment to fix the rest.

Comment: @zdim: Yes, I'm sorry that I was unclear. You made pretty much the same edits that I would have done. I was referring to the OP's first comment, *"It does compile and run"* which is untrue. It may have been useful to describe the syntax errors that you had to ignore when reformatting, but it's also a warning for me as I often make similar edits without comment.

Comment: @Borodin  Good point. I should have absolutely stated in that comment that it does not compile and noted at least what I spotted. Not to forget in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to convert

```
my $hex = "0123456789aBcDeF";
```

into

```
my $bytes = "\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\xAB\xCD\xEF";
```

To do that, simply use

```
my $bytes = pack 'H*', $hex;
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you. It seems to be packing them correctly.  I just can't seem to get those values to write out the file.  I have this code

my $filename = 'Hub_Device_ID.txt';
my $outfile= 'Hub_Device_ID.bin';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
open(my $of, '>:raw', $outfile)
  or die "Could not open file '$outfile' $!";
 binmode($of);
  
while (my $row = <$fh>){

  chomp $row;
   print "Chomped row\n";
 print $row, "\n";
 

 my $bytes = pack 'H*', $row;
 print $bytes, "\n";
 printf $of pack("NN", $bytes);

Comment: Why are you printing `pack("NN", $bytes)` instead of `$bytes`?